# Word for a relationship specifying that 2 objects don't affect each other

Tags: data-structure

I am aiming to create an Enum for a terrain_surface_layer.type property. The 3 types of terrain_surface layers I wish to implement are the following:

1. Single - only a single type of terrain_surface is placed on this layer
2. Mixer - when a terrain_surface is placed on this layer, terrain_surfaces that overlap this new terrain_surface have their effectiveness on the terrain reduced. The totality of effectiveness of the set of terrain_surfaces at a particular point on the terrain_layer is 1, eg the effectiveness is a sum of exclusive effectiveness of each terrain_surface.
3. Disjoint - any terrain_surface can be placed on this layer without any implicit constraints/validation on the terrain_surface being placed

How else would you describe a Disjoint relation of this type? This type of relationship between objects is not exclusive to this particular functionality and I am sure I will encounter it again.

Comment: I don't see how this is specific to game development. It would be better suited for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It isn't. But I didn't want to post a completely abstract question, which usually doesn't get an answer or may be rejected, so the game dev implementation that prompted it was specified. This game dev functionality may also have an expected convention in engines. Anyway, the answer is independent/indep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Decoupled**, or **Independent**

[Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/independent?s=t)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **Cosmetic**, if it provides no other effects other than visual ones.